About submeasures
A submeasure on $\omega=\{0,1,2,...\}$ is a function $\varphi : \mathcal P(\omega) \to [0,\infty] $ such that for all $A,B \subset \omega $ we have:

$\varphi(\emptyset)=0 $

if $A \subset B$ then $\varphi(A) \le \varphi (B) $

$\varphi(A \cup B)\le \varphi(A)+ \varphi(B)$

$\varphi(\{n\}) < \infty$ for all $n \in \omega $.


I am wondering whether every submeasure $\varphi $ satisfies the following statement:
$$ \varphi(\bigcup_{i \in \mathbb N}A_i) \le \sum_{i \in \mathbb N} \varphi(A_i) $$
I tried to prove it, but I couldn't. So, is it wrong?
